# How can i allow custom tags and attributes html?

Tags: php, html

i want to use custom tags and attributes html,

In this example i want to use a tag and i want to allow only href attribute.

```
 $test = "<a href='#' onmouseover=alert(9) >BBB</a>";

 echo strip_tags($test,"<a>");
```

Comment: How's your REGEX?  If not good (mine isn't), lookup the `explode` command

Comment: There's not going to be a simple function built into php to perform this.  http://htmlpurifier.org is a library made for sanitizing html inputs, I suggest you start there.

Comment: i want to use a simple framework to do that is there any framework to do that

Comment: How did the `a` tag reach till here? I mean how did you get this in `$test`?

Comment: @vivek_23 it's just an example

Comment: @YusufHR There is no nice way to achieve this on server side. Processing this on client side is much better.