# custom HTML tags and attributes

Tags: javascript, html

I'm really kind of struggling at the moment and I don't know how hard it can possibly be.
I followed several different tutorials and answers here on SO and YouTube, but all are doing it differently and I am kind of stuck right now.

All I want is a `custom HTML-Tag` with some `custom attributes`

I tried it with this approach (JS)

```
class MyTrophy extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
    super();

    var rarity = this.getAttribute("rarity");
    console.log("rarity: " + rarity);
    }
}

customElements.define("my-trophy", MyTrophy);
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <my-trophy rarity="silver" id="someID">lorem ipsum</my-trophy>
</body>
```

> The JS-File is loaded in the header of the HTML-File

Since it is not an object as well, I cannot log the `my-trophy` tag as well. It is planned, that I have multiple tags of these kind in my final dom.

It doesn't matter what I try, I don't get the rarity-attribute to work. Am I supposed to just use `data`-attributes for that case, even though this here is a custom HTML tag?

References:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNbOarODRzE
- [How can i allow custom tags and attributes html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52155724/how-can-i-allow-custom-tags-and-attributes-html)
- [How to create custom tags for html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682943/how-to-create-custom-tags-for-html)
- https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/

Some of the methods simply don't work (anymore?) (for example, it seems like `registerElement` isn't available anymore, but there is defineElement now).

I would expect, if I log `console.log(rarity)`, that the output would be "silver".

For the completness of the question: I'm trying to run the script in `Google Chrome`

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran your code and it worked just fine with the `constructor`, but you could try [`connectedCallback`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45133477/1762224) instead. This method gets called any time an element is added to the document.

Make sure your script runs in the `<head>` of the document, before your `<body>` is executed. HTML/scripts run top-to-bottom. Your element needs to be registered before it is rendered.

**Update:** Please refer to the ["Custom elements" - *JavaScript.info*](https://javascript.info/custom-elements) article that was linked by Martin Braun for a better understanding. The official MDN documentation can be viewed here: ["Using custom elements" - *MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements).

```js
class MyTrophy extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    const rarity = this.getAttribute('rarity');
    console.log(`Rarity: ${rarity}`);
  }
}

customElements.define('my-trophy', MyTrophy);
```

```css
my-trophy {
  font-size: 3em;
}

my-trophy[rarity="silver"] {
  color: #777;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<my-trophy class="fas fa-trophy" rarity="silver"></my-trophy>
```

Comment: Interesting, with `connectedCallback()` it works. I wonder why that is. Will accept this answer as soon as I can. Still weird that it works for you, while it doesn't for me. Thank you! I should have added the information, that I'm running this on chrome.

Comment: @DasSaffe For more information, check [this article](https://javascript.info/custom-elements). It explains all the callbacks of custom elements.